# How to disable the checkbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a list of checkboxes on view page for to send notifications for different roles.I want to disable some checkboxes in unchecked state initially.

I am working with following code in view

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in NotificationList  | filter:{Media: item.Media}" ng-if="!collapsedNotification" ng-class="{'pad-top-4':($first)}" >
                                    <label for="NotificationLabel" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label font-normal" title="{{notification.NotificationLabel}}">{{notification.NotificationLabel}}</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"  style="line-height:35px;">
                                <span  class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 item-padding ">
                                    <span class="default-pointer" ng-checkbox  ng-init="ToAdmin=false" ng-model='ToAdmin' ng-click="disableClick()" ng-disabled="ToAdmin"></input>

                                </span>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="line-height:35px;">
                                <span  class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 item-padding ">
                                    <span class="default-pointer" ng-checkbox ng-model='notification.ToNutritionist'></span>                                        
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"  style="line-height:35px;">
                                <span  class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 item-padding ">
                                    <span class="default-pointer"  ng-checkbox ng-model='notification.ToPatient'></span>                                        
                                </span>
                            </div>
                                   </div>
```

How can i disable the checkboxes(in unchecked state) for specific roles in controller using angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng-disabled` property.

Like this example :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="disable=!disable">

<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disable">
```

Comment: As @alexis said you can use ng-disabled property.

Implementation depends on the scenario in your application

<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="expression"> // This is a method of implementation

If the expression is truthy, then the disabled attribute will be set on the element

Comment: yes. I have already worked with it but it is not working. <span class="default-pointer" ng-checkbox  ng-init="ToAdmin=false" ng-model='ToAdmin' ng-click="disableClick()" ng-disabled="ToAdmin"></input>

Comment: Don't use <span ng-checkbox> then and use 
<span><input type="checkbox" ng-disable="expression"></span>